# Can I save spoiled indian pickle?

Tags: indian-cuisine

If there is already small spoiling from water on pickle, can I salvage this in any way? Please help.

Comment: I don't understand "small spoiling from water."  Can you explain?

Comment: @moscafj Agree. But if it is already spoiling, I don't think it's worth saving. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: In India it is commonly believed than any small amount of water will cause pickles to spoil.  See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/can-water-cause-fermented-pickles-to-spoil

Comment: ...is "you are working with traditional techniques that are outside the "mainstream" food safety framework, heed any traditional advice that comes with these techniques" acceptable answer here?

Comment: I read question 25155 and my curiosity is piqued even more.  I would really love a scientific explanation, and will keep digging.  So far, I've learned that Indian pickles probably undergo lactic fermentation, but typically have oil (often mustard oil) as an ingredient.  It is not yet clear whether or not the water-spoilage comment has a scientific basis, but I have seen it mentioned a few time in some searching.  I don't think @rackandboneman 's comment is acceptable, as food science/safety applies regardless of tradition.

Comment: What I meant is "there might be exceptions, due to some scientifically reasonable but undocumented/not "formally scienceinatored" facts hidden in the traditional methods. Applying mainstream food safety rules permissively here could cause unsafe conditions."